# comparison operator not working in ie7 jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am having a problem with this JQuery in ie7, it works perfectly in chrome, firefox, and ie8/9. I've scoured the internets to no avail. It just doesn't want to change the src attribute, which leads me to believe it's failing at the if test.

```
var active = '/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/active.png';
var inactive = '/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/inactive.png';
if ($(this).attr('src') == inactive) {
    $(this).attr('src', active);
    $('.navbutton').not(this).attr('src', inactive);
}
```

The line below works in ie7, outside of an if test, so i'm not exactly sure what the problem is. Anyone know what's going on?

```
$('#navbutton0').attr('src', active);
```

Comment: What's `$(this)`, can you post the context?

Comment: When you `alert($(this).attr('src'))`, what does it say?

Comment: $(this) is referring to the .navbutton class, the if test is inside of 
`$('.navbutton').each(function(index){`
`$(this).on("click", function(event){`

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that in the beginning :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$(this).attr('src').indexOf(inactive) >= 0` instead as your if test condition. I think I noticed IE7 was sometimes adding extra stuff to the src, such as the full path.